# Battery gets discharged...sometimes!

Tags: electrical, electronics, battery-drain

This is one of those intermittent issues driving mad any car driver:

What I have:

New battery, new alternator brushes, new current regulator, new belt. Polished brushes tracks. All properly installed.

Problem is: sometimes the battery gets discharged in a 20 to 40 minutes evening trip. Not completely out, but not enough to crank the starter. This new battery comes with the magic eye, green means good, black means discharged. When this happens it obviously turns to black.

The car came with an amp meter in the dashboard. In any case, it shows good readings when the engine is running. When the engine is in idle it is a bit off the 0 +, when accelerating the needle moves towards the end of the scale if I gas it enough. During driving, the amp meter always shows some + reading. I guess, the alternator is dishing some juice, right?

But even under that circumstances, sometimes the battery gets discharged. In those cases, I can see lights dim on idle, getting brighter when gassing the engine.

So...what to blame?

Car is a 1970's Fiat 126p...no electronics, no computers, no fancy stuff, carburated, alternator with external regulator, regular headlights 90/50, no stereo. Just a bareback pony :)

Comment: Good to see you, Aram! Interesting issue :o)

Comment: Is there a battery drain when the ignition is off?

Comment: A 1970 fiat should have 60/55 headlights. You should measure the demand as well as alternator output - if they are equal then there is none left to charge the battery...

Comment: Weird. You are not talking about an Electric car right, which consumes battery for its movement :D

Comment: Depending on how the ammeter is connected, it can show a 'positive' reading because there is current flowing from the battery to the lights and accesories. That is, if it is wrongly connected to the battery *after* the dynamo. It'll never show a negative rating then. If it's an oldskool DC generator with external regulator, it shouldn't deliver any current at idle(kicks in only after revvig it up), so the ammeter should show a negative reading at idle. If it is a more modern alternator then this is not an issue. If the regulator is connected wrong, the battery will discharge through the dynamo

Comment: @GdD: no, there isn't any current leak when key is off.

Comment: @Bart: interesting: the amp meter never shows negative reading, always 0 and towards +. This is a 70's car, I guess the alternator is of such kind you describe, i.e. no output on idle, but I need to check that. It is a Magneti Marelli I think 14v 33A, and originally it comes with an integrated regulator, but it got broken so they attached an external one then.

Comment: Fiat used external regulators long after most other manufacturers moved to integrated ones : Lada continued using them as they continued the older designs based on Fiat : I was asked to change diode packs in a series of alternators for the area I worked in by the local dealership...

Comment: @Bart if the ammeter is connected between the alternator and the battery then it will only ever show a positive current - when it is connected between the battery and all the electrics including the alternator it will show current into and out of the battery - when it is connected between the battery and the electrics but not the alternator it will show discharge ie the electricity being used by headlights etc. This is all dependant on the ammeter being correctly connected.

Comment: @SolarMike That's just what I explained.. But i didn't have words left to elaborate, so you probably understood me incorrectly. Point of the story is; ammeter should be installed directly after the battery, so only the current into or out of the battery gets monitored. This excludes the starter motor of course.

Comment: @Bart There are three places to put an ammeter - it just depends exactly what you want it to show or what you want to test for : which is what I explained.

Comment: @SolarMike We're talking about the car's ammeter which OP mentioned right? That should only be placed directly aftger the battery. Of course placing a multimeter somewhere will give more insight, but that isn't what the question is about.

Comment: @Bart depends what is wanted , some were only showing generator or alternator output - it does, I suppose, depend on what variety of vehicles one has worked on ....

Comment: I believe the amp meter is in parallel with the power wire from the battery: I have three wires there, thick one for the starter and two much thin. I'm guessing one is the power line, the other then may be the amp meter. I will check tomorrow. So far it is charging, I found that the regulator ground connector is just a wrap around a bolt in the rear quarter :) In fact, I found all connections are using pieces of wires with connectors twisted to their longer wire :P I will sanitize that.

Comment: After making a better ground connection for the regulator it seems it is charging, the only difference in this evening driving was that it wasn't raining so I didnt used the wipers. I wonder if the wiper motor is faulting, eating too much power

Comment: Is the ammeter original equipment or aftermarket fitment?  There is a chance that it is that actual item that is causing the problem.

Comment: Interesting. After I re did part of the car wiring, I got the battery charging just fine for a few days and evening trips. However a couple of days ago I got the "almost-dead" symptom again. Although the battery didn't discharged completely. In the day after, it charged ok. What I found is that the amp meter is getting a bit hot...is it normal?